# Rename files depending on original consecutive numbering - lowest to highest number

Tags: windows, batch-file

I deleted the files `2.png` and `5.png` - is there a way to adjust numbering to be consecutive again? (retain original order from lowest to highest number)

turn

```
1.png   
3.png  
4.png  
6.png
```

into

```
1.png   
2.png  
3.png  
4.png
```

Comment: That's actually not the question. I simplified my question.

Comment: You should clarify further, I think.  Otherwise, we're still guessing.  Now, based on the edit, it sounds like you want to rename 1_3.png to 1_2.png, after you deleted 1_2.png, etc. and continuing forth as such after.  Is *that* correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Well you'd probably need to completely change your approach. I say that because until you've deleted your fles, you do not know which have been deleted in order to renumber them. My best guess therefore is that you simply need to search for a renumbering script, after having made your deletions. The two tasks aren't really linked, and trying to do them as a single process will be difficult to say the least.

Comment: It was the question until you changed it.

Comment: Doe it matter which files get which names? *(I don't expect that is should, because there's nothing in your current naming schedule which identifies the content of the files by their names alone.)*

Comment: Well, it matters that the general order is not different after renaming was done.

Comment: What is the criteria used in the current naming schedule? Is `1` the oldest and `6` the newest? and if so, is the age determined by modified, created, accessed etc? All we can be sure of, from your example, is that their numbering is not determined by their file sizes.

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: The `1_` part of the filenames, do not alter the complexity of what you're asking, if you cannot  divulge the current naming schedule criteria. Let's say we expand your provided file set, to include `1_7`, `1_8`, `1_9`, `1_10`, `1_11`, `1_12`, `1_13`. When you viewed in name order in Explorer, they'll be in this order, `1_1`, `1_10`, `1_11`, `1_12`, `1_13`, `1_2`, `1_3`, `1_4`, `1_5`, `1_6`, `1_7`, `1_8`, `1_9`. Obviously if you delete `1_2` and `1_5` in this case, `1_10` and `1_11`, which were listed second and third positions, will now be listed second last and last respectively in the list!

Comment: Regardless of all of that, this site provides assistance with a specific issue with the code you've provided for undertaking the task laid out in your question. However the code you've provided is complete irrelevant to the task, you've not attempted to rename anything. If you do not post code exhibiting an issue, we cannot help you to fix it. Currently all you've done is poorly explain a generic task, and seem to be expecting to receive a programming methodology and/or code for achieving it. Your question is therefore off topic, we don't provide a coding service or general programming advice.

Answer (score 1):

That's it - since it was important to get the original file order intact.

```
set "id=0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /od "*.png"') do (
set /a "id+=1"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%b in (!id!) do endlocal & ren "%%~fa" "%%b.png"
)
```

Comment: Just imagine how much quicker we'd have got to this point, if you'd have answered my question in the comment area. You've obviously decided that the original sort criteria was based upon the date. Just be aware that it would assist future readers of your code, and that may even include yourself one day, if you were to specifically use the `/T` option with `C`, _( Creation date and time)_, `A`, _(last Accessed date and time)_, or `W`, _(last Written date and time)_; e.g. `Dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W *.png`. Please also note that this selects files with extensions beginning with, not exactly, `.png`.

Answer (score 1):

Just one suggestion for use with leading zeros and also observing **[@Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo)**
comment on the use of flags: **`/O:D /T:W`**:

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~pd0" 
call set "_id="<nul && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /b/a:-d/o:d/t:w *.png
')do set /a "_id+=1+10000" && %ComSpec% /v/c "ren "%%~fi" "!_id:~-3!.png""
```

After that you can also list in order by name `dir /on`, and get the same results even though you have changed / modified some of the files.

Files names date test:

```bat
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             7,484 img_1.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             7,466 img_6.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             8,048 img_5.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             8,047 img_4.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             6,549 img_3.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM            17,015 img_2.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             7,484 img_0.png
04/05/2020  11:03 PM            22,606 img_8.png
04/05/2020  11:04 PM            24,352 img_15.png
04/05/2020  11:11 PM           291,531 img_14.png
04/05/2020  11:12 PM           171,579 img_13.png
04/05/2020  11:12 PM           294,257 img_12.png
04/05/2020  11:34 PM            17,314 img_11.png
04/05/2020  11:34 PM            21,709 img_10.png
04/05/2020  11:35 PM           256,188 img_9.png
05/02/2020  12:31 PM           313,573 img_7.png
05/11/2020  09:24 PM           337,141 img_16.png
```

File results name:

```bat
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             7,484 001.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             7,466 002.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             8,048 003.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             8,047 004.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             6,549 005.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM            17,015 006.png
03/04/2020  05:46 PM             7,484 007.png
04/05/2020  11:03 PM            22,606 008.png
04/05/2020  11:04 PM            24,352 009.png
04/05/2020  11:11 PM           291,531 010.png
04/05/2020  11:12 PM           171,579 011.png
04/05/2020  11:12 PM           294,257 012.png
04/05/2020  11:34 PM            17,314 013.png
04/05/2020  11:34 PM            21,709 014.png
04/05/2020  11:35 PM           256,188 015.png
05/02/2020  12:31 PM           313,573 016.png
05/11/2020  09:24 PM           337,141 017.png
```

If you need more zeros, edit:

```bat
Increase set/a from 10000 to 100000
')do set /a "_id+=1+10000"

%ComSpec% /v/c "ren "%%~fi" "!_id:~-3!.png""
Use last ~-X digits you need in  :~-4!.png""

')do set /a "_id+=1+10000" && %ComSpec% /v/c "ren "%%~fi" "!_id:~-4!.png""

File name result layout: 0001.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set n=1
for %%a in (*.png) do (
ren %%a !n!.png
set /a n+=1
)
```

Comment: Whilst this could work given a specific environment it is certainly not a solution unless we can guarantee that environment. Your code does not determine any order whatsoever, it simply relies on the `*.png` to list them in the order you hope it will, and there is no way we can guarantee it, especially without knowing the naming schedule criteria, how many files there are, _(and/or what numbers they go up to)_, the target filesystem etc.

Comment: @Compo The for loop goes through the files in alphabetical order. That's the numerical order, provided all the numbers have the same number of digits. If not he has to fix that first.

Comment: It doesn't, and I'm really not in the mood to start to explain, all of the possibilities, Suffice to say, it may appear from tests on certain file systems that it outputs them in alphabetical order, but that is not something you can guarantee. Regardless of that, whilst it works with just a small number of single digit integers, on your particular system/volume/environment, as soon as it reaches `10`, the alphabetical order places `10` after `1`, not after `9`, so your solution would in any case modify the original ordering.